# jquery conflict between dropdown menu and ajax window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have a jquery dropdown menu and an modal window which is a trigger for ajax. The problem occurs when you click on link for ajax, and when you close it dropdowns are not working anymore. So dropdown is working when you dont click the ajax. When you click the link and close it, dropdown menu is not showing dropdown.

Try it and source code are here:

```
codepen.io/riogrande/pen/NxZLaQ
```

Step by step to reproduce:

1. Mouse over the right most "Lorem" and a drop down menu appears.
2. Exit the mouseover and click the link titled "Click here for ajax"
3. Click the "X" to exit the ajax popover
4. Step 1 no longer works.

Comment: @mkaatman thanks for edit, this was needed!

Comment: that codepen reference produces a 404 error at this time

Comment: the link is editet @MarkSchultheiss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use separate `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` functions instead of a single `fadeToggle` on hover and it will fix the issue:

```
$(".menu-dropdown").hover(
  function(e) {
    if ($(window).width() > 943) {
      $(this).children("ul").stop(true,false).fadeIn(150);
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  },
  function(e) {
    if ($(window).width() > 943) {
      $(this).children("ul").stop(true,false).fadeOut(150);
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
);
```

CodePen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjgRGW).

Comment: You are the boss, Thank you so much for your answer!!! Could you just explain me, why would this make the conflict, and how did you even think about this part?

Comment: I editet my comment and added a question, could you explain me why would this be the conflict, shoud I do this for click event to? and how did you go in that direction? Is it better to have fadeIn and fadeOut on all jquery examples ?

Comment: Could you please answer me?

Comment: Sorry, I've just seen the change in your comment. Well, my experience shows that `fadeToggle` can be a real problem, especially when combined with `hover`. As a personal preference, I never use it, even with `click` events, and if something looks wrong with fade effects, I immediately check use of `fadeToggle` first. I probably shouldn't say "Don't use it.", but well, if you do not have to, don't...

Comment: thanks man, i was even searching for your email to ask you that, thanks for infos!

Comment: No problem. Sorry, again.

Comment: How would i do the same thing for click function? Now i have the same problem on click but your solution applied on click is not working, menu wont open?

Comment: In order to understand what it is about, I need to see your exact code first.

Comment: http://codepen.io/riogrande/pen/NxZLaQ     -   same bug, open ajax and close it on destop width and submenu is not working (you solved that) , and when you put mobile width of browser, open ajax, close it and then dropdowns are not working on mobile menu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104299/discussion-between-arman-ozak-and-riogrande).