# Jquery toggle Effects or separated effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was having an issue when i had a jquery conflict between jquery driven menu and ajax. 
You can see the conflict here: [jquery conflict between dropdown menu and ajax window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35540630/jquery-conflict-between-dropdown-menu-and-ajax-window)

Basically the menu was not working once you close the ajax modal. The conflict was fadeToggle effect on menu hover which was toggling sub-menu. To clear it, person who helped me said the answer is to separate the effect in two parts: fadeIn and fadeOut, like this

jquery:

```
$(".menu-dropdown").hover(
  function(e) {
    if ($(window).width() > 943) {
      $(this).children("ul").stop(true,false).fadeIn(150);
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  },
  function(e) {
    if ($(window).width() > 943) {
      $(this).children("ul").stop(true,false).fadeOut(150);
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
);
```

My question is, why would that be the conflict? And should i always separate effect states in jquery? Should i avoid toggle effects and classes everywhere with jquery and allways separate this states?

Comment: I think you should ask this question to the thread you taken this code from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35541164/4354249

Comment: did you actually try the code to see if it solved the problem?

Comment: code is solving the problem, i need explanations